# How to rotate PDFAnnotation using PDFKit (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I am working on PDF Kit using swift. I want to rotate PDFAnnotation. Is there any way to rotate PDFAnnotation? I am trying with the below code but I am not successful to get the desired result.

```
annotation.bounds.origin = annotation.bounds.origin.applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -90 * CGFloat.pi / 180.0))
```

[image: Please see the attached image to know about my requirement]

Comment: Hi Sac, I am following your other question about annotation scaling too. Did you able to find a solution for this. Thanks!